# Find a set of vectors that spans $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a set of points that satisfies $\begin{bmatrix}a-b\\b-c\\c-a\\b \end{bmatrix}$, with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. Decide if $A$ is a vector space and if so, choose a set of vectors that span $A$. It seems a bit tedious to check for all the properties of a vector space, so I thought that it might be easier to check if $A$ is a subspace of another space, like $\mathbb{R}^4$.

- Id: $A$ contains the zero vector (e.g let $a=b=c=0$)
- Closure under addition: For $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\begin{bmatrix}a-b\\b-c\\c-a\\b \end{bmatrix}$ + $\begin{bmatrix}z-y\\y-z\\z-x\\y \end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}(a+x)-(b+y)\\(b+y)-(c+z)\\(c+z)-(a+x)\\b+y \end{bmatrix}$.
- For scalar (real) multiplication I suppose it is quite straight forward.

I am having difficulties when it comes to finding a set of vectors of the given form that spans $A$. A hint or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $a=1, b = 0, c=0$ then $\pmatrix{1\\0\\-1\\0}$ is a vector in your vector space.  Then set $(a,b = 1$ with holding the othe variables at $0,$ to find a second vector.  etc.

Comment: @DougM I don't quite follow, what is the method?

Comment: @DougM I think I understand your method now, given Dave's answer. I was just confused when you wrote $a,b=1$, I guess you meant $b=0, a,c=0$ for the second vector?

Comment: Sorry, small typo in there.  Set $a = 0, b = 1, c = 0$ for the second vector and $a = 0, b = 0, c = 1$ for the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three parameters $a,b,c$ in the general vector. So you want to split up the general vector into a sum of three vectors, each of which involving only one parameter. What I mean is, write
$$\begin{bmatrix}a-b\\b-c\\c-a\\b\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
so the first vector only involves $a$, the second only involves $b$, and the third only involves $c$. Then you can see that these three vectors (on their own, without the $a,b,c$) span the subspace.

Comment: Thank u very much, great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can write $A = \{ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3 \mid a,b, c \in \mathbb R\},$ where $e_1 = (1,0,-1,0), e_2 = (-1,1,0,1),$ and $e_3 = (0,-1,1,0).$ Then it should be very easy to see that $A$ is a vector space, namely the space spanned by those three vectors. They are even linearly independent, so they are a basis for $A,$ and $A$ is a 3-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^4.$

Comment: I understand your solution now, thanks!